# magento: how to add javascript to my main page?

Tags: magento

I am using Magento, and I don't know where to add js blocks, to be display in my main page (first page that comes up).

Where do I need to add the code?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "js blocks"? If this code is related to something like a JS homepage slider, then you would only need to load it into your homepage file (probably homepage.phtml if you haven't changed anything).

If this is something along the lines of Google Analytics, you may want to add this JS block to footer.phtml and it will show on ever page AFTER the content of your site has finished loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do:
to add a normal js file from you `js` folder go to you home cms page and switch to the tab "Design" under "Layout Update XML" you can add something like this

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs"><script>your-js-file.js</script></action>
</reference>
```